# Azure function stuck in timeout loop

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-blob-trigger

We have a Azure Function at work that stopped working so I got tasked to debug it and found that it gets stuck in a timeout loop right of the bat.
I don't have that much experience with Azure Functions so I thought perhaps a very basic function might work, but gets the same fault with that as well.
Using Azurite for storage emulation.

Python 3.11.5, Azure.functions 1.17.0

This is my function:

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

logger.warning('This is a warning')
logger.error('This is an error')

def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    filename = os.path.basename(myblob.name)
    content = myblob.read()

    # Your code to process the blob content goes here
    # For example, you can print the blob's filename and length
    print(f"Blob name: {filename}")
    print(f"Blob length: {len(content)} bytes")
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "singleton": {
    "listenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15" 
  }
  
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "function_app.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/default/ECO_DAYINV904951960411607774_231019%20from%20231018.xlsx",
      "source": "EventGrid",
      "connection": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
  ]
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/blobs?functionName=Host.Functions.BlobTriggerEventGrid",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

I've tried to debug this, but can't get it to stop at a breakpoint, so I need to pause it and at that point it is already in the timeout loop in the common.py function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an Azure function with a blob trigger using runtime stack Python.

I have made some changes to your code and executed it successfully.
**function code:**

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 
# Create handlers
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
 
# Create formatters and add it to handlers
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
 
# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
 
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    # Log a message
    logger.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob\n"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
 
    filename = os.path.basename(myblob.name)
    content = myblob.read()
 
    # Your code to process the blob content goes here
    # For example, you can print the blob's filename and length
    print(f"Blob name: {filename}")
    print(f"Blob length: {len(content)} bytes")
```

loca.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "your connection string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "storepavan3_STORAGE": "your connection string"
  }
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  }
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
      "connection": "storepavan3_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

output:
[image]

When I put breakpoints in the code, I got hit in the code.
check below:

[image]